# Save step variable in github action not working

Tags: github-actions

I have followed existing online documentations to come up with this code that save the variable `file_size` in the step bellow, however it's always blank, even when there are files avaliable, what am I doing wrong?

```
- name: Get modified files
  id: files
  uses: umani/changed-files@v3.3.0
  with:
    repo-token: ${{ github.token }}
    pattern: '^src.*\.(py)$'
    result-encoding: 'string'
- name: Check files size
  id: file_check
  run: |
    echo ::set-output name=file_size::$(printf "%s" "${{ steps.files.outputs.files_updated }} ${{ steps.files.outputs.files_created }}" | wc -m)
    echo 'MESSAGE<<EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV
    echo  "No valid file found, skipped"  >> $GITHUB_ENV
    echo 'EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV
- name: Lint with pylint
  if: steps.vars.file_check.file_size > 1
```

This is the run result:

[image]

The bash command is correct as I tried it online:

[image]

So that just mean the variable isn't saved in github action, how come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the value to $GITHUB_ENV

like so:

```
echo "file_size="$(printf "%s" "${{ steps.files.outputs.files_updated }} ${{ steps.files.outputs.files_created }}" | wc -m) >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Otherwise the value will not persist.

Answer (score -1):

Alright fixed:

```
- name: Check files size
      id: file_check
      run: |
        echo "file_size="$(printf "%s" "${{ steps.files.outputs.files_updated }} ${{ steps.files.outputs.files_created }}" | wc -m) >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo 'MESSAGE=No valid file found, skipped' >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Comment: Would be good to describe what the issues was instead of just posting the solution.